# How to calculate the overhead of an amount

Tags: c#, algorithm

I would like an algorithm to calculate the overhead of an amount based on

Scale table :

- < $10,000  =>  13%
- $10,001 - $100,000  => 8%
- $100,001 - $1,000,000  => 6%
- $1,000,001 - $5,000,000  => 4.9%
- $5,000,000  => 3%

> if user enters $6,000,000
>
> the expected output
>
> $10,000 * 13% = $1,300
>
> $90,000 * 8% = $7,200
>
> $900,000 * 6% = $54,000
>
> $4,000,000 * 4.9% = $196,000
>
> $2,000,000 * 3% =  $60,000
>
> ------------------------ Total: $ $318,000
>
> if user enters $5,000
>
> the expected output
>
> $10,000 = $5,000 + 13% = $650
>
> $90,000 = 0 + 8% = $0
>
> $900,000 = 0 + 6% = $0
>
> $4,000,000 = 0 + 4.9% =  $0
>
> $2,000,000 = 0 + 3% =  $0
>
> --------------------------- Total = $650

Here is the code I have had so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Amount: $");

        var amount = 115000m;
        var scales = ScaleCalculator.GetScales(amount);



        Console.ReadKey();
    } 


}
public class OverheadAmountScale
{
    public string ScaleTitle { get; set; }

    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public decimal Rate { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount
    {
        get
        {
            return decimal.Round(Value * Rate, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"${this.Value} * {this.Rate}% = ${this.Amount}";
    }
}
public class Scale
{

    public decimal Value { get; set; } 

    public decimal Rate { get; set; } 

}

public static class ScaleCalculator
{
    public static List<OverheadAmountScale> GetScales(decimal amount)
    {
        var amountScales = new List<OverheadAmountScale>();

        var scales = new List<OverheadAmountScale> {
            new OverheadAmountScale { ScaleTitle ="< $10,000", Value = 10000m, Rate = 0.13m },
            new OverheadAmountScale {  ScaleTitle ="$10,001 - $100,100",Value = 90000m, Rate = 0.08m },
            new OverheadAmountScale { ScaleTitle ="$100,001 - $1,000,000",  Value = 900000m, Rate = 0.06m },
            new OverheadAmountScale { ScaleTitle ="$1,000,001 - $4,000,000", Value = 4000000m, Rate = 0.049m },
            new OverheadAmountScale { ScaleTitle ="> $5,000,000", Value = 5000000m, Rate = 0.03m }
        };

        var scaleAmounts = new List<OverheadAmountScale> {
            new OverheadAmountScale { ScaleTitle ="< $10,000", Value = 0, Rate = 0.13m },
            new OverheadAmountScale { ScaleTitle ="$10,001 - $100,100", Value = 0, Rate = 0.08m },
            new OverheadAmountScale { ScaleTitle ="$100,001 - $1,000,000", Value = 0, Rate = 0.06m },
            new OverheadAmountScale { ScaleTitle ="$1,000,001 - $4,000,000", Value = 0, Rate = 0.049m },
            new OverheadAmountScale { ScaleTitle ="> $5,000,000", Value = 0, Rate = 0.03m }
        };

        if (amount <= 0)
        {
            return scaleAmounts;
        }


        var accumelatedValue = 0m;
        scales.ForEach(s => {
            // when above limit value
            if(amount >= s.Value)
            {
                amountScales.Add(
                    new OverheadAmountScale
                    {
                        ScaleTitle = s.ScaleTitle,
                        Value = s.Value,
                        Rate = s.Rate
                    });
                accumelatedValue += s.Value;
            }
            else
            { 
                amountScales.Add(
                  new OverheadAmountScale
                  {
                      ScaleTitle = s.ScaleTitle,
                      Value = amount - accumelatedValue,
                      Rate = s.Rate
                  });
            }
        });

        return amountScales;
    }
}
```

Comment: SO is not a free code-writing service. This is for good reason, as people learn best by doing. Please show what you've tried and, if you get stuck, let us know  what exactly you're stuck on.

Comment: @ Maryom You can find similar questions by searching for `[c#] tax table` here on SO.

Comment: @MaryomShehadeh There's a search box at the top of this page. Type `[c#] tax table` into that search box and press enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 public class OverheadAmountScale
 {
    public string ScaleTitle { get; set; }

    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public decimal Rate { get; set; }

    public decimal OverHeadAmount
    {
        get
        {
            return decimal.Round(Value * Rate, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        }
    } 
 }


 static List<OverheadAmountScale> GetScales(decimal amount)
    {
        var amountScales = new List<OverheadAmountScale>();

        const decimal TOP_THRESHOLD = 5000000m;
        const decimal HIGH_THRESHOLD = 1000000m;
        const decimal MEDIUM_THRESHOLD = 100000m;
        const decimal LOW_THRESHOLD = 10000m;
        const decimal BASE_THRESHOLD = 0m;


        const decimal TOP_THRESHOLD_FACTOR = .03m;
        const decimal HIGH_THRESHOLD_FACTOR = .049m;
        const decimal MEDIUM_THRESHOLD_FACTOR = .06m;
        const decimal LOW_THRESHOLD_FACTOR = .08m;
        const decimal BASE_THRESHOLD_FACTOR = .13m;

        decimal amountWorkingRange = amount;

        decimal OverheadDue = 0;

        if (amountWorkingRange > TOP_THRESHOLD)
        {
            var lineOverheadTOP = amountWorkingRange - TOP_THRESHOLD;
            amountScales.Add(
            new OverheadAmountScale
            {
                ScaleTitle = $">= ${(TOP_THRESHOLD + 1).RoundResultNoDecimal().ToString("N0")}",
                Value = lineOverheadTOP,
                Rate = TOP_THRESHOLD_FACTOR,
            });
            amountWorkingRange = TOP_THRESHOLD;
            OverheadDue += lineOverheadTOP;

        }
        if (amountWorkingRange > HIGH_THRESHOLD)
        {
            var lineOverheadHIGH = amountWorkingRange - HIGH_THRESHOLD;
            amountScales.Add(
             new OverheadAmountScale
             {
                 ScaleTitle = $"${(HIGH_THRESHOLD.RoundResultNoDecimal() + 1).ToString("N0")} - ${TOP_THRESHOLD.RoundResultNoDecimal().ToString("N0")}",
                 Value = lineOverheadHIGH,
                 Rate = HIGH_THRESHOLD_FACTOR,
             });
            OverheadDue += lineOverheadHIGH;
            amountWorkingRange = HIGH_THRESHOLD;
        }
        if (amountWorkingRange > MEDIUM_THRESHOLD)
        {
            var lineOverheadMEDIUM = amountWorkingRange - MEDIUM_THRESHOLD;
            amountScales.Add(
             new OverheadAmountScale
             {
                 ScaleTitle = $"${(MEDIUM_THRESHOLD + 1).RoundResultNoDecimal().ToString("N0")} - ${HIGH_THRESHOLD.RoundResultNoDecimal().ToString("N0")}",
                 Value = lineOverheadMEDIUM,
                 Rate = MEDIUM_THRESHOLD_FACTOR,
             });
            OverheadDue += lineOverheadMEDIUM;
            amountWorkingRange = MEDIUM_THRESHOLD;
        }
        if (amountWorkingRange > LOW_THRESHOLD)
        {
            var lineOverheadLOW = amountWorkingRange - LOW_THRESHOLD;
            amountScales.Add(
             new OverheadAmountScale
             {
                 ScaleTitle = $"{(LOW_THRESHOLD + 1).RoundResultNoDecimal().ToString("N0")} - ${MEDIUM_THRESHOLD.RoundResultNoDecimal().ToString("N0")}",
                 Value = lineOverheadLOW,
                 Rate = LOW_THRESHOLD_FACTOR,
             });
            OverheadDue += lineOverheadLOW;
            amountWorkingRange = LOW_THRESHOLD;
        }
        if (amountWorkingRange > BASE_THRESHOLD)
        {
            var lineOverheadBASE = amountWorkingRange - BASE_THRESHOLD;
            amountScales.Add(
              new OverheadAmountScale
              {
                  ScaleTitle = $"<= ${LOW_THRESHOLD.RoundResultNoDecimal().ToString("N0")}",
                  Value = lineOverheadBASE,
                  Rate = BASE_THRESHOLD_FACTOR,
              });

            OverheadDue += lineOverheadBASE;
            amountWorkingRange = BASE_THRESHOLD;
        }
        return amountScales;
    }
}
```